# Arduino: Custom class for display does not work; no compiler errors

Tags: c++, c, arduino, display

I tried to make a class to make the usage of the a dispaly with the ucg lib more convenient. I think the main problem is that i use a instance of the ucg class as member of my own class. But the code seems correct and i do not get any compiler errors. Still my Display does nothing.

Note: The pins are correct

Header file:

```
#ifndef Display_h
#define Display_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include "Ucglib.h"

class Display
{
    public:
        Display(int sck, int mosi, int ds_rs, int cs, int reset);

    private:
        Ucglib_ILI9341_18x240x320_SWSPI _display;
};

#endif
```

Cpp File:

```
#include "Display.h"

Display::Display(int sck, int mosi, int ds_rs, int cs, int reset) : _display (sck, mosi, ds_rs, cs, reset)
// Constructor for the display class
{
    delay(1000);
}
```

Edit:

Testprogramm: The seriell monitor of the Arduino IDE does not show the Text "Test", so i guess the programm gets stuck somewhere in the construtor.

```
#include "Display.h"

const int sck = 7;
const int mosi = 6;
const int ds_rs = 5;
const int cs = 3;
const int reset = 4;

Display lcd = Display(sck, mosi, ds_rs, cs, reset);

void setup() 
{

  Serial.begin(115200); 
  Serial.println("Test");
}
```

Comment: Please short it down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'd be very surprised if the `Ucglib_ILI9341_18x240x320_SWSPI` instance would object to being a member of another class. Have you been able to write some little test program to verify that the display is working? Can you build on that to show when it doesn't work?

Comment: @TedLyngmo thx for the fast reply. I tried to slim it down and also add the test prgramm i used to find out where the problem is. I have a programm where the display works but there i use the Ucglib_ILI9341_18x240x320_SWSPI class directly in the .ino file.

Comment: use `Display lcd(sck, mosi, ds_rs, cs, reset);`

Comment: As @Juraj mentions, the above does not look right to me. You are trying to allocate it dynamically, but then the variable type is not a pointer, and a `new` is missing.

Comment: @Juraj when i try your solution the result is still the same.

Comment: the pins are not hardware SPI pins of Uno or Mega used by the SPI library

Comment: @suvayu i tried the folowwing : Display* lcd = new Display(sck, mosi, ds_rs, cs, reset) ; 
But it also did not chnage the result

Comment: @Juraj okay, but i used the same pins in another programm where i used the Ucglib_ILI9341_18x240x320_SWSPI class directly and it worked

Comment: and why do you include SPI.h? or why do you use software SPI?

Comment: @Juraj good point, i copied the inludes from somewhere else and forgot to delete that one. My bad

Comment: shouldn't you have `begin()` for the display? what Arduino you have? do you see "Test" if you comment out the display variable?

Comment: @Juraj i use the begin() function later. I use an Arduino Uno. Yes if i comment out my display variable i see "Test". I just saw that if i put my disdplay variable inside void setup() everything works just fine. But then i can of course not use it in my loop since it is out of scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `delay(1000);` in the constructor of the class. The variable is defined before `setup()` and delay can't be executed there. The execution of the sketch crashes there.

Remove the `delay` from the constructor of class `Display`.

Comment: Is `delay` prohibited there because it is outside the event loop?

Comment: delay() uses micros() and the timer for micros() is initialize in main() before calling setup(). global variables are initialized before main()